# How to format code in Xcode INCLUDING MarkUps

Tags: swift, xcode, formatting, comments, markup

I Know that using Xcode is possible to format code using **Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent** the issue I'm having is when I want to Re-Indent all my code including markUps like this:

```
/**
     Append new motive to motives array
     - parameters:
        - name: A brief description of motive.
     - returns: false if is empty otherwise true
*/
```

**Note:** if I select all my code and Re-Ident it the MarkUp code will look like this :

```
/**
     Append new motive to motives array
     - parameters:
     - name: A brief description of motive.
     - returns: false if is empty otherwise true
*/
```

This going to affect the  Quick Help shown, I've added both pictures before indent and after it.

Before Indent Quick Help:

[image: Before Indent Quick Help]

After Indent Quick Help:

[image]

Look that after Indent my Code the Quick help is not shown as it has to be, look specially the **parameters** row it disappear because it needs to be indent from `- parameters:` one tab.

The questions is how can I Indent my code including the appropriate indent to MarkUps or how can I select all my code Indent it but not affect the MarkUps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks kind of bugs not fixed yet. 
I recommend the way of below for description of parameters.

#### Basic (Same way with [Apple Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SymbolDocumentation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH51-SW1))

```
/**
 Append new motive to motives array

 - parameters name: A brief description of motive
 - parameters opt: A options

 - returns: false if is empty otherwise true
 */
public func exampleFunc(_ name: String, options opt: Options) {
  ...
}
```

But I prefer to use with auto indentation of XCode.

#### With Auto Indentation(Recommend way)

```
/**
Append new motive to motives array

- parameters name: A brief description of motive
- parameters opt: A options

- returns: false if is empty otherwise true
*/
public func exampleFunc(_ name: String, options opt: Options) {
  ...
}
```

It will make format always same even use auto indentation.