# Xcode 11.2.1 re-indent breaks markup syntax format

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, comments

I'm writing comments to functions in Apple suggested syntax. When I add parameter list to comment, It is needed to be written with one space gap for each parameter element. Example below;

```
/**
 Creates boxview with curreny selection component + spending values component. If it is a cutoff card It also adds total card limit.
 - Parameters:
  - param1: Card which determines that how to initialize box components
  - param2: delegate that passes data between CreditCardTermViewController and CreditCardInTermViewModel.
  - param3: Localization strings
 */
```

**My problem** is that when I re-indent code with `CTRL + I`, It deletes the one space gap before each parameter so that they don't act like they are parameter when I open quick help section of the function;

```
/**
 Creates boxview with curreny selection component + spending values component. If it is a cutoff card It also adds total card limit.
 - Parameters:
 - param1: Card which determines that how to initialize box components
 - param2: delegate that passes data between CreditCardTermViewController and CreditCardInTermViewModel.
 - param3: Localization strings
 */
```

I'm using Xcode 11.2.1. How can I solve this problem?

There is an example question asked but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. In addition, I don't want to add parameter keyword at the beginning of every element If there is a better way to solve it.
[How to format code in Xcode INCLUDING MarkUps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742343/how-to-format-code-in-xcode-including-markups)

Answer (score 0):

I have two observations. Firstly, if you use the `///` style i.e.

```
    ///
    /// Creates boxview with curreny selection component + spending values component. If it is a cutoff card It also adds total card limit.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///  - param1: Card which determines that how to initialize box components
    ///  - param2: delegate that passes data between CreditCardTermViewController and CreditCardInTermViewModel.
    ///  - param3: Localization strings
    ///
```

The indentation is preserved.

Secondly, the style of using `-Parameters:` and then listing the parameters is broken in the Xcode editor. The callout on <kbd>alt</kbd> `click` doesn't format them properly anymore.

If you use the <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> command you'll get

```
    ///
    /// Creates boxview with curreny selection component + spending values component. If it is a cutoff card It also adds total card limit.
    ///
    /// - Parameter param1: Card which determines that how to initialize box components
    /// - Parameter param2: delegate that passes data between CreditCardTermViewController and CreditCardInTermViewModel.
    /// - Parameter param3: Localization strings
    ///
```

which still works.